# No provider for InjectionToken ng.v5.defaultTsConfig

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr

I have a problem when I was execute npm run build. In the terminal an error appears:

**No provider for InjectionToken ng.v5.defaultTsConfig! (InjectionToken ng.v5.packageTransform -> InjectionToken ng.v5.initTsConfigTransform -> InjectionToken ng.v5.defaultTsConfig)**

Additional information, I'm using the library:

- "@angular/animations": "14.2.8",
- "@angular/common": "14.2.8",
- "@angular/compiler": "14.2.8",
- "@angular/core": "14.2.8",
- "@angular/forms": "14.2.8",
- "@angular/platform-browser": "14.2.8",
- "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.2.8",
- "@angular/router": "14.2.8",
- "ng-packagr": "14.2.2",

How to fix it? I got a similar question, but still no answer : https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/2261

Comment: did you added defaultConfiguration in angular.json

Comment: do you have an example? because at the time before the migration to 14, without having to add defaultConfiguration. npm run build can be execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `defaultConfiguration`

```
         "development": {
           "tsConfig": "projects/my-library/tsconfig.lib.json"
         }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
      }
     },
     "test": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
```